# loader constraint java linker

Tags: java, gradle

Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader  previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/joda/time/DateTime"

I think this is a problem with two jars loading the same plugin. I am using gradle as my automated build system - how do I get around this?

I've tried

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force "sourceforge:joda-time:2.0"
  }
}
```

but I think this isn't working because all that's doing is forcing one version of joda-time.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Does this error occur when running a specific task? If yes, which one? Also, please show the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

That exception usually indicates either an incompatibility between two or more components running in the same JVM (especially between those used by a container and a contained).

Yes, it could be related to loading two different versions of the same plug-in.

As I've not been in that specific situation, I only can suggest to use JVM option

```
-verbose:class
```

or similar (depending on JVM make/version) to better identify the conflict.